# Run a method once per iteration without adding a component to a game object in Unity

Tags: unity

I want to run a function once per main loop iterator but I don't want to add this as a script to a game object in my scene. This is something that should always run no matter what scene and making people include it into every scene on a game object would cause issues because I'll/people will forget. Is there any hooks into the main loop where I can tell unity to run this function once per loop for the entire game not just per scene?

Comment: Every script that need run a update loop need derive from MonoBehavior what you asking for is impossible without script sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create directly from the script a gameobject as a singleton marked as `DontDestroyOnLoad`: this way, the gameobject will be persistent during the entire duration of the runtime.

Note that you have to create a game object in the first scene loaded, or you won't be able to execute the `Update` method. With this script, however, you don't need to physically create the game object in the editor, it's created automatically by the script itself only at runtime.

This is the code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class AutoSingletonScript : MonoBehaviour {
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Initialization() {
        if (FindObjectOfType<AutoSingletonScript>() != null)
            return;
        var instance = new GameObject { name = "AutoSingleton" };
        instance.AddComponent<AutoSingletonScript>();
        DontDestroyOnLoad(instance);
    }

    private void Update() {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you very much. This really is like a hook into the main loop!